# QFT and mathematical rigor

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

One way to approach QFT in mathematical terms is provided by the so-called Gårding-Wightman axioms, which defines in rigorous mathematical terms what a quantum field theory is supposed to be. If I'm not mistaken, this is what is called *axiomatic QFT*. Although it is a precise mathematical theory, it is widely known that to construct examples of quantum field theories which are proved to satisfy these axioms is no easy task and, as far as I know, only a few such theories were constructed by now.

Now, to better pose my question, let me use a specific theory in QFT, which is the Klein-Gordon theory, as an example. We can, for instance, follow the exposition of [Folland's book](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/books/postpub/surv-149) and give mathematical meaning to such theory by defining the correct (single particle) Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$, giving meaning to creation and annihilation operators as operator-valued distributions in the associated Fock space and obtaining the expressions for the associated quantum fields.

Although this construction is, in practice, using some ingredients of what's expected in the axiomatic construction, it *seems* to me that these two approaches have different phylosophies: the axiomatic approach tries to construct a theory which fulfills every one of its axioms while the second one seems more pragmatic and tries to take what is written in the physics literature and convert it to a mathematical precise language.

The non-axiomatic approach does not intend to check if its objects satisfy any kind of axioms; it is almost like it was a 'dictionary' that translates the physical theory to a mathematical audience. As a consequence, it seems less technical and more compatible with what is written in the physics literature.

**Question:** So, my question is: why do we need an axiomatic approach to formalize QFT? Is there any limitation with the non-axiomaic approach? Are both approaches research material, i.e. different practices of the current attempts to give mathematical meaning to QFT?

Comment: "axiomatic construction" here is an oxymoron. That's because the axiomatic approach does not construct anything. It just sits there waiting for you to construct some mathematical object and when you do, it will say yes this is a QFT, or no this is not a QFT. Likewise "non-axiomatic approach" is a non-approach by any mathematical standard.

Comment: @Abdelmalek hahaha that's true.

Comment: Btw, "Garding" (with a "d"), apart from the diacritical mark above the "a", ... ?

Comment: @paulgarrett the "g" instead of "d" was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I think the issue is that it is really difficult to rigorously construct interacting quantum field theories. Here you can imagine axiomatic QFT as the "gold standard" for what we want; if someone purports to construct an interacting theory, you can measure that against the axioms. Physicists and mathematicians agree that free field theories (e.g., Klein-Gordon) are rigorously understood. But the standard model is an interacting theory.

Comment: When all you have to work with are only a few concrete examples of "QFT", then you can't prove or disprove any statement that starts with $\forall$"QFT". To do that, you need to take off the quotes and give an actual definition, and this is where axiom systems like Whitman's come in. Of course, the choice of axioms has to be flexible, to actually accommodate examples that people care about (as already point out in other comments/answers).

Comment: It is certainly desirable to have a mathematically rigorous axiomatic formulation of QFT, but it seems unlikely that this would lead to any new physics results. This is my opinion from what I have seen of the literature but one which is shared by others including some of the leading field theorists like Banks and Weinberg.

Comment: Well, it depends on what you call "new physics results". There are quite a few important conceptual loose ends on axiomatic QFT that may have an impact on physics. Two of them are: (a) how to rigorously define QFT scattering theory with both massive and massless particles, and (b) how to rigorously define resonances in QFT. Both are directly linked to experiment and still are very poorly understood.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As Abdelmalek Abdesselam pointed in his comment to the OP, the axiomatic approach to QFT is rather concerned with answering the question "what is a quantum field?". This is stated right at the Preface of the book of Streater and Wightman, *PCT, Spin and Statistics, and All That*. More precisely, it lists a minimal set of desiderata for a reasonable concept of a "quantum field", and deals with the consequences of such requirements, which can be thought of as "structural" or "model-independent". It leaves open the question of which fields used in physics actually satisfy these requirements, apart from checking that free fields do. This is important as a first relevance check, since free fields are the easiest to mathematically control - if not even a free field complies with a list of axioms for QFT, then these axioms are useless as they stand and should be modified. More generally, any list of mathematical axioms applied to a class of physical theories is bound not to be set in stone, since our knowledge of Nature is always approximate due to our limited experimental precision. One should rather see such axioms (and their limitations in the given context) as general physical principles whose robustness has to be constantly tested, in addition to forming a well-defined mathematical framework by themselves. Such is the way of natural sciences.

In that respect, it must be remarked that indeed *not all* physically relevant fields satisfy the Garding-Wightman axioms - most notably, fields acting in Krein spaces (i.e. "Hilbert" spaces with a possibly indefinite scalar product), such as the electromagnetic potential in a covariant gauge, do not. The corresponding axiom for vacuum expectation values that fails is that of *positivity*. There are ways to extend the Wightman formalism to such fields, but the results are nowhere near as mighty of even as rigorous, since positive definiteness of the scalar product is a powerful constraint. Another tricky example are *perturbative* (renormalized) quantum fields, since these are *formal* power series in the coupling constant (convergence of the renormalized perturbative series is usually expected to fail). One must in this case keep track of the order-by-order structure of all series involved, and to define certain concepts invoked by the Garding-Wightman axioms such as positivity is far from trivial. Regarding renormalization, the main conceptual challenge is not so much the ultraviolet problem (which is rigorously well understood on a formal perturbative level), but the infrared problem, which plagues all interacting QFT models with massless fields and is not completely understood on a rigorous level, even in formal perturbation theory. And all that before even considering how to extract some non-perturbative definition of the model from perturbative data by employing e.g. some generalized summability concept for the perturbative series.

This order of doing things - namely, stating a list of general desiderata and then checking if models comply with it or not - is what is often called a "top-down" approach to QFT. What people such as Folland try to do is rather a "bottom-up" approach: trying to make sense of the formal procedures physicists actually use in (perturbative) QFT. A more successful way of doing what Folland tries to do is achieved by the so-called *perturbative algebraic QFT*, which draws ideas from the Haag-Kastler algebraic approach to QFT (which is a different axiomatic scheme from that of Garding and Wightman, aiming at aspects which do not depend on the particular Hilbert space the fields live in) in order to mathematically understand formal renormalized perturbative QFT (summability of the perturbative series has not been addressed yet in this approach). The so-called *constructive* approach to QFT also fits in such a "bottom-up" philosophy: it tries to build QFT models by means other than perturbation theory, in view of its expected divergence in relevant cases (Abdelmalek can tell you far more than me on that). Once one has obtained the model, one may try to e.g. check the Wightman axioms (or some suitable modification thereof) in order to see if the model obtained complies with that particular notion of QFT, which is undoubtedly relevant.

To sum up, I would say that both approaches are important and complement each other.

Comment: again thank you for the answer! This was really enlightening and I feel happy to understand a little more by having such contact with experts on the subject!

Comment: Do you know if $\phi^4$ theory (scalar field with quartic potential) fits in any axiomatic approach? And abelian (say Maxwell, with $G=U(1)$) gauge theory? And, more ambitiously, nonabelian gauge theory (with $G=SU(2)$, say)?

Comment: @JulesLamers $\phi^4$ models have been constructed for $d=2,3$ and $d>4$ space-time dimensions, and are known to satisfy the Wightman axioms. However, for $d>4$ the interaction doesn't survive after non-perturbative renormalization, i.e. the theory is free (trivial). The case $d=4$ is still open. Pure Abelian gauge theories are non-interacting and are not hard to constructed rigorously, apart from the fact that in covariant gauges the field acts on a Krein space, as mentioned above. Pure non-Abelian Yang-Mills is known (I think) for $d=2$, but for $d=4$ only in finite volume.

Comment: @PedroLauridsenRibeiro Thanks. Does this apply for Lorentzian as well as Euclidean signature?

Comment: (continued) Massless QED in $d=2$ (Schwinger model) is equivalent to a free field theory and hence is not difficult to construct. Massive QED in $d=3$ has been recently constructed (2020) also in finite volume by Dimock. The case of $d=4$ QED is also open - both QED and $\phi^4$ in $d=4$ are believed to be trivial, but this is based on information coming from partial resummation of the perturbative series, so it's hard to tell for sure at our current state of knowledge.

Comment: @JulesLamers As a rule, if the theory has been completely constructed and satisfies the Euclidean version of the Wightman axioms - the so-called Osterwalder-Schrader axioms - one can recover the theory in Lorentzian signature, which will then satisfy the Wightman axioms. This cannot be done if one only knows the Euclidean theory in finite volume, as it's the case for QED in $d=3$ and pure Yang-Mills in $d=4$. In the case of non-interacting models, the construction is done directly in Lorentz signature if the lack of interaction is know a priori. This was *not* the case for $\phi^4$ in $d>4$.

Comment: @PedroLauridsenRibeiro Thanks a lot for this summary of the state of the art for some of the prototypical examples of QFT

Comment: Do you know any good introductory material to Krein spaces?

Comment: One has the classic book by J. Bognár, *Indefinite Inner Product Spaces* (Springer-Verlag, 1974).

Comment: @Pedro, do you know if this is what is usually assumed to "define" Hilbert spaces in physics books? I've heard several times "this Hilbert space has an indefinite inner product" or even  "A Hilbert space is a vector space with a positive-definite inner product" but I never understood this assertions. So actually the difference is between Hilbert spaces and Kreub spaces?

Comment: A complex (resp. real) Hilbert space is a complex (resp. real) vector space $V$ endowed with an inner product, that is, a positive definite Hermitian (resp. symmetric) sesquilinear (resp. bilinear) form $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ whose associated norm $\|x\|=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$ makes $V$ a *complete* normed vector space. In finite dimensions completeness is automatic. Physicists tend to abuse language when they speak of inner products, sometimes including indefinite but still nondegenerate Hermitian (resp. symmetric) sesquilinear (resp. bilinear) forms into the above definition.

Comment: About $\phi^4$ in $d=4$, the problem is not that open anymore. Confirming RG based predictions by physicists, Aizenman and Duminil-Copin have proved triviality in an article soon to appear in Annals of Math https://annals.math.princeton.edu/articles/17711

Comment: (continued) In this case, strictly speaking one is really no longer talking about Hilbert spaces, but about the more general Krein spaces. For those, one can still define a topology and a notion of completeness (which may be defined for any topological vector space, since completeness depends only on the uniform structure associated to a vector topology), but the procedure is far more complicated. The book by Bognár I quoted above studies this matter in depth.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam whoa. That's impressive. Thanks for the important news!

Comment: Pedro you mention that Euclidean Yang-Mills theory for $d=4$ is constructed in finite volume, do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @Blazej: See this article by Magnen, Rivasseau and Sénéor https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-155/issue-2/Construction-of-rm-YM_4-with-an-infrared-cutoff/cmp/1104253284.full and references therein to work of Balaban and Federbush.

Answer (score 2):

Let me enter the arena with the statement that there is a basic problem with the Wightman-Gårding system.  To put it baldly the central concept, that of an observable- valued distribution, is defined(implicitly) in a way that is simultaneously too strong (leads to difficulties in constructing models) and too week (difficulties in proving theorems).  At the heart of quantum theory lies the fact that the observables are represented by unbounded s.a. or normal operators.  Since these play the role of the real and complex numbers in this context, it would seem to be imperative to develop a parallel theory there, including the basic ideas of real and complex analysis—regularity conditions (continuity, measurability, smoothness) of observable-valed functions and functions between observables, differentiation of such functions, series expansions (Taylor, Hermite, Fourier) and, most importantly for QFT, observable-valued distributions.  It seems that I need to emphasise that these are a priori purely mathematical questions—in my opinion, highly interesting ones, completely independent of any relations to physics of any sort.  Of course, the fact that there are such relations (not just in quantum theory, by the way) increases this interest.

The basic mathematical structures required for a rigorous development of QFT are the concepts of holomorphic functions and distributions with values in in the space of observables, i.e., the self-adjoint, resp., normal unbounded operators on a (say, separable) Hilbert space.  I am arguing that a major stumbling block for a construction of the former is the lack of a suitable definition of these concepts.

Before proceeding to the constructive part of my posting, let me note that the Wightman-Gårding axioms implicitly give a definition of observable-valued distributions which assumes that all of the operators which occur have the same domain of definition. I would claim that this is much too strong as simple examples show—consider (in the holomorphic case) the family $T(z)=(z^n)$.  This can be regarded as a family of complex sequences and hence of normal operators (by multiplication on $\ell^2$) dependent on $z$.  It should plainly be, by definition, an observable-valued entire function but fails the stringent conditions imposed by the axioms on the domains of definition.  A further example is the function $z\mapsto I+zA$ for an unbounded normal $A$.  This should plainly be holomorphic but fails the condition on the domains of definition.

The axioms are often stated in a weaker form, demanding only that there be a dense subspace contained in the domains of the operators
but this is hopelessly inadequate—if you know a s.a. operator on a dense subspace, you know nothing. Think of the Laplace operator on some domain in euclidean space regarded as an operator on the smooth functions with compact support.  Without boundary conditions, and there are many candidates, this is not s.a.  In fact, this operator defined, say, on the test functions has uncountably many self adjoint extensions and if we label them with a complex variable $z$ we get a wildly pathological observable which is holomorphic since it is constant on a dense subspace.

We remark that we have displayed these functions in the context of holomorphicity for simplicity but the ideas apply equally in other contexts.

Given the inadequacy of this definition, it can be no surprise that there are no indications in the literature of a general theory of observable-valued distributions or holomorphic functions (the usual basic things—functoriality, differentiation, series developments—Taylor or Hermite, for example, and so on).  I am prepared to place my head on the block and claim that there never can be such a mathematically rigorous theory based on the above definition.

Now for the positive remarks.  I will concentrate on the case of holomorphic functions since this is the most transparent one but many other spaces of functions and distributions can be handled analogously.  We begin with the remark that the extension of the concepts of smoothness of functions to the vector case (Banach spaces, locally convex spaces, even topological vector spaces, although the latter is rather delicate) was carried out over 50 years ago, for example by Schwartz and Grothendieck).  in carrying this over the the case of observables, there are a number of stmbling blocks—the natural ingredients—topological and algebraic structures (addition and multiplication of observables)  are no longer available, or rather they are but in much more delicate forms). The starting point is that the space of observables has a natural topology for which it is a polish space.

If $U$ is a complex domain (to be specific), the we denote by $H(U)$ the space of holomorphic functions on $U$ and its dual by $H(U)‘$.  It helps, but is not essential, that the former is a nuclear Fréchet space and the latter has a concrete representation as a space of holomorphic functions on the complement of $U$ in the Riemann sphere (Sebastião e Silva, Köthe).

Grothendieck extended the work of the latter by showing that the space of holomorphic functions on $U$ with values say in a Banach space $E$ can naturally be identified with $L(H(U)‘,E)$, the continuous linear operators on the dual into $E$.

This makes it natural to define the observable-valued holomorphic functions on $U$ to be the space of continuous linear operators from $H(U)‘$ into the space of observables.  Since the latter is not a tvs (or even a vector space),  the latter requires some explication.  The continuity creates no problems (the space of observables has a topology).  Linearity uses the rather subtle concept of addition for unbounded s.a. or normal operators—for which see the standard literature, e.g., Reed and Simon.  We say that a mapping with values in the space of observables is linear if $T(\alpha f)=\alpha T(f)$  for all $\alpha$ and $T$ and for each $f_1$ and $f_2$ the operators $T(f_1)$ and $T(f_2)$ have a sum, with the usual equality holding.

In the case of distributions, say tempered—the ones most used by physicists, the same definition applies, using operators on the Fréchet space of rapidly decreasing smooth functions.

We remark briefly that these spaces have the basic properties that one uses , e.g., for constructing and computing with models, in perturbation arguments, etc. and which fail under the Wightman-Gårding axioms.

Tho holomorphic functions contain the classical ones (i.e., with values in the bounded operators), they can be differentiated (I emphasise—not true in W-G—who ever heard of not being able to differentiate holomorphic functions?), have Taylor expansions and are functorial property in dependence of the domain of definition (which means that symmetry groups there lift to the fields).

With regard to distributions, similar remarks hold—they can de differentiated, expanded in terms of the Hermite basis, Fourier transformed, symmetries of the underlying euclidean space operate on them and they contain, as a special case, the classical ones (i.e., with bounded operators as values).

Since this posting has become uncomfortably long, I will close with the fact that these concepts have the properties which one would reasonably expect from a theory of observable-valued holomorphic functions or distributions and so could serve as the basis for a more rigorous approach to QFT.

Some quotes:

Kazhdan: Physics is very interesting.  There are many, many interesting theorems. Unfortunately, there are no definitions.

Zeidler.  In mathematics one never does calculations with quantities that do not exist.

Jost: The fact that intuition barely can guide us forces us to use standards of rigour usually frowned on in theoretical physics.

Comment: Your initial statement that there is a "lack of a suitable definition of these concepts" is not really true, for several reasons.

Comment: (1) if one is worried how one defines quantum fields as "distributions valued in unbounded operators in a Hilbert space", specially regarding w.r.t. which topologies such distributions are continuous, one must remember that such operators can be defined in terms of *-representations of a nuclear locally convex *-algebra - to wit, the tensor algebra generated by the space of (tempered) test functions  / vector / tensor / spinor fields, also called the Borchers-Uhlmann *-algebra.

Comment: (continuation of (1)) The ${}^*\!$-representation is built from a state in this ${}^*\!$-algebra (that is, a positive linear functional equaling one on the identity), which is nothing else than the sequence of Wightman n-point (tempered) distributions. The Wightman axioms can be equivalently formulated in terms of these. The recovery of the quantum field operators, the Hilbert space where they act and their common domain of definition therein is a consequence of the so-called *Wightman reconstruction theorem*, which is a version of the GNS representation for (non C)${}^*\!$-algebras.

Comment: (2) The analytic structure of the quantum fields which follows from the Wightman axioms is expressed by that of the n-point functions, viewed (as well as their Fourier transforms) as boundary values of holomorphic functions, as you suggested. However, if you want fo extend the Wightman axioms to other spacetimes (with the spectral condition replaced by possibly some suitable microlocal variant), this analytic continuation of the n-point functions is no longer possible is the space-time is not real-analytic (as many physical examples thereof indeed aren't).

Comment: (3) If you want to deal with the structure of quantum field theories in a representation-independent manner and focus on the observables - or, more appropriately, on the relative inclusions of the algebras of observables localized in each space-time region -, the Wightman formalism should be replaced by the Haag-Kastler algebraic approach to QFT, based on (C)*-algebras. This is needed because e.g. (a) quantum fields are often not directly observable, and (b) the whole state space of a QFT cannot fit into the Wightman-GNS vacuum Hilbert space, among other things.

Comment: (4) Not even for free fields it's always true that smeared quantum fields are normal operators in the Wightman-GNS Hilbert space - they are at best only closable in the domain $D$ generated by the action of the Wightman-GNS *-representation of the Borchers-Uhlmann *-algebra on the vacuum state vector. The continuity of the quantum field operators as operator-valued distributions holds in the weak sense, that is, for its matrix elements between state vectors in $D$. This is clear since these can be written directly in terms of the Wightman n-point functions.

Comment: (5) The relation of quantum fields to observables can be quite complicated. For instance, most relevant observables are not linear in the field operators. For example, to get the local C*-algebras of observables of the (real) Klein-Gordon field (which does happen to be essentially self-adjoint in $D$), the most direct way is the exponentiate the smeared field in order to obtain the Weyl unitaries, which are bounded. In the case of Dirac fields, the smeared field operators are bounded but no longer observable and one has to proceed instead to the smeared current operators, ans so on.

Comment: You contest my statement that there is no rigorous definition of the concept of a distribution or holomorphic function with values in the space of unbounded self-adjoint or normal operators in the literature.  I would be  very grateful if you could back this up with an explicit reference.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: (continuation from (5)) In that sense, it's indeed not true that the Wightman formalism cannot be written in terms of observable-valued distributions, but for a much deeper reason: for most QFT models, *linear* maps from test functions / sections into local algebras of observables simply cannot take *observable* values, period. This is a physical feature of QFT, not so much a mathematical one, and happens regardless of any choice of topology. That's why the Haag-Kastler approach looks at local algebras of observables as the main object, regardless of the way we construct it in term of fields.

Comment: One just has to look at the Wightman formalism written in terms of n-point distributions (the vacuum expectation values), as I sketched in (1) and (4) above. The classic book of Streater and Wightman on axiomatic QFT, *PCT, Spin and Statistics, and All That* does that in great detail. For an explicit description of the Borchers-Uhlmann *-algebra for a real scalar field, one may look e.g. at https://mathoverflow.net/a/216380/11211 or https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/90032/16767 , especially the work of K. Maurin quoted in the latter.

Comment: In due time: I don't assume in the above that the test functions / distributions are tempered, but this assumption can be included in a straightforward manner. Temperedness is used mainly to open access to the Fourier transform, absolutely indispensable in order to analyze the action of the space-time translation group and the energy-momentum spectral condition. This can be weakened in several ways.

Comment: A more modern presentation, probably more focused on the functional-analytic aspects you're interested in, can be found in the books by K. Schmüdgen, *Unbounded Operator Algebras and Representation Theory* (Birkhäuser, 1990) and *An Invitation to Unbounded Representations of ${}^*\!$-Algebras on Hilbert Space* (Springer-Verlag, 2020).

Comment: Could you please point out directly in the literature with chapter and verse a definition of the following concepts a) a distribution with values in the space of unbounded self adjoint  operators b) a holomorphic function with values in the space of unbounded, normal operators c) a holomorphic function beteen unbounded, normal operators?

Comment: For (a), I've presented such a definition in (1), (4) above. For (b), one just identifies the distribution given by each matrix element between vectors in the domain with a holomorphic function. You criticize the fact that in the Wightman formalism one is given a common domain of definition, but this is justified by the Wightman reconstruction theorem. As for (c), I don't see how it's relevant for QFT, by the points I made above. One cannot impose a mathematical language at a given level of generality on a physical topic without first justifying why it's relevant to do so in the first place.

Comment: In (a), (b) the operators being normal or self-adjoint in the context of the Wightman formalism depends on additional properties of the n-point distributions. As I explained in (4), this is not always the case. Again, this is dictated by physical principles, as it can be seen in examples (e.g. free quantum fields).

Comment: Perhaps the missing point to understand why Wigjtman fields are defined the way they are, which is implicit in (1) but needs to be emphasized, is that the smeared quantum fields form a ${}^*\!$-algebra. This is just how quantum fields are defined in physics and is encoded in the Wightman-GNS *-representation. The common domain of definition follows from that naturally. So, even if these particular unbounded operator-valued distributions are not as general as wished in your answer, they have the right level of generality as dictated by physical principles and are mathematically well defined.

Comment: As for imposing holomorphy, again, one needs to justify why this is relevant for QFT. The fact that Wightman n-point distributions are boundary values of holomorphic funcions is a consequence of the Wightman axioms of temperedness, microcausality and the spectral condition, all of which have a physical origin. Depending on the physical context, some of these axioms are no longer valid (e.g. in curved space-times), and one then no longer is physically justified in requiring holomorphy. The latter should be seen as a consequence, not as a requirement.

Comment: The starting point of our discussion was your claim that something that I stated was „not really true“, in other words false.  What I stated was that there is no adequate definition of two concepts, those of holomorphic functions and distributions with values in the space of observables in the literature (whereby it is the latter which is used in, say, Wightman and Gårding—I mentioned the issue of holomorphicity for the sake of transparency).  It is a matter of logic that the falseness of my claim means that there are such definitions .  I can only repeat my request for a precise reference.

Comment: I repeat that the question of the nature of the definition of observable-valued analytic functions or distributions is a purely mathematical one which is a priori independent of any kind of physics, let alone QFT.  Of course, the motivation for considering them is based on the latter.  It is surely perfectly natural and legitimate for a mathematician who repeatedly reads phrases such as  „a quantum field is a distribution with observables as values“ to request a precise definition of the latter.  I assumed that such questions were central to the theme „QFT and mathematical rigor“.

Comment: Perhaps I should qualify my original claim, sorry for that. What I meant is that the concepts of distributions with values in unbounded operators - and, particularly, with values in normal or self-adjoint ones - *is* properly developed under an additional set of hypotheses suitable *for the purposes of QFT*, which is the context of the OP's question. That is so because the Wightman axioms have fundamentally physical origins. As I expounded in my answer, mathematical axioms for a class of physical theories cannot be thrown out of nowhere just because one wishes it to be so.

Comment: If you aim to describe a class of physical theories axiomatically, these axioms should express the underlying physical principles of these theories. If you come up with axioms which don't describe theories in this class, you are not reaching your aim, regardless of your axiomatic approach being mathematically consistent and non-trivial. Then I ask: what is the actual connection of the approach you advocate to QFT *as used in physics*? One thing is QFT as it is, quite another is something you wish it were.

Comment: If you want more details about how the Wightman framework yields unbounded operator-valued distributions, look at e.g. Sections 3-3 and 3-4 of the book of Streater and Wightman. The Wightman reconstruction theorem is the whole theme of Section 3-4 - more precisely, Theorem 3-7, pp. 117-126. The books of Schmüdgen are entirely about this topic (at least, in the context relevant to the field algebra structure of QFT) - I cannot point to a specific result, one should read them in depth.

Comment: Just requiring the fields to be observable-valued (i.e. taking values in normal or self-adjoint operators) is not only too broad, but also inaccurate. As I pointed in (5) with several concrete examples, observables are usually not linear in the test function arguments, and linear observable fields are rather the exception than the rule. That's why the ${}^*\!$-algebra structure of quantum fields is more fundamental, physically speaking. Even more fundamentally, one should rather see the ${}^*\!$-algebra of quantum fields as a "coordinate ring" for the local observables of the theory.

Answer (score 0):

At some level, the basic difference between the two approaches is one of philosophy, or perhaps personality.  The central issue, as one of my physics professors put it, is "The nice thing about mathematics is that it describes all possible logically consistent universes.  The problem with physics is that we live in precisely one."  The goal of physics is to *determine which one*.  Mathematics begins with choosing axioms, and proceeds by proving theorems in formal logic; physics begins with experiments, and proceeds by inventing and discarding theories according to their statistical agreement with those experiments.

Proof, to a physicist, means correctly predicting the result of experiments, regardless of whether the approach used makes mathematical sense.  Renormalization in QFT has been described as "subtracting infinity from infinity to obtain a result accurate to twelve decimal places."  To a physicist, this is a *triumph*.  It does not matter that we are summing power series we know don't converge, because twelve decimal places is by far the best we've ever done!  The fact that the formal manipulations seem ludicrous -- what are we to make of analytic continuation in the number of dimensions of spacetime? -- is irrelevant, so long as they continue to get close enough to the answers experiments lead us to believe might be right.

I have a good friend who specializes in constructive QFT in the Wightman tradition, and I was once quite interested in it myself, but I have come to feel that while it may eventually produce interesting mathematics, its physical relevance is diminishing.  I chose physics over mathematics for graduate school largely because it meant I need not choose a mathematical specialty -- I could do differential geometry and algebraic number theory and a variety of other things all at the same time, so long as I could claim some connection to a situation in nature considered confusing by physicists.  I eventually found that I had made the right choice for the wrong reason, when I realized it mattered more to me to describe nature than to make logical sense.

The great question in modern physics is how to combine quantum field theory with general relativity.  Each is very successful in predicting particular situations, but each claims the other is impossible at a basic level, as in the well-known nonrenormalizability of the gravitational field.  However, since it is very difficult to construct experiments with objects that are both extremely small and extremely heavy, physicists have become increasingly dependent upon mathematical logic to guide us in choosing which tool to attempt next.  String theory has made valuable contributions to four-dimensional topology, but it remains to be seen whether the worlds it describes include the one we inhabit.

The way physics is taught is another illustration.  We teach Newtonian mechanics to children *knowing that it is wrong*, because it is good training in thinking like a physicist, and provides predictions of moderately acceptable accuracy and thus good practical utility in many common real-world situations.  We teach nonrelativistic quantum mechanics to undergraduates *knowing that it is wrong*, for exactly the same reasons.  We continue to use both general relativity and quantum field theory *while believing that both are wrong*, since neither one has yet been surpassed in predictive accuracy in its chosen domain.  Once they are, we will no doubt continue using them as well as their successor, in any situation where nature allows us to get away with doing so.

If we eventually happen to stumble upon the exactly correct theory of everything, then its axiomatization may yield physically interesting results; but until then, I am forced to regard axiomatic approaches to physical laws as mathematics done for its own sake.  There's nothing wrong with that, but it's not physics until it can predict the numerical results of experimental measurement.

Comment: Saying Newtonian mechanics gives "moderately" acceptable accuracy is underselling its importance.  It gives acceptable accuracy, period, for designing buildings on Earth or predicting orbital trajectories of basically all spacecraft sent out to explore the Solar system (mid-course corrections are made all the time, irrespective of relativity).

Comment: Pushing the summary to slight extremes for effect, I find this more of an answer of "why physicists don't need the axiomatic approach to QFT" rather than the original question of "why mathematicians need the axiomatic approach to QFT".